# Android. How to change size of view from java code

Tags: java, android

I have this problem.
I have an Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
   public View m_top_overlay;
   private MyFrameLayout m_preview;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    m_preview = (MyFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_preview);  
    m_top_overlay = (View) findViewById(R.id.top_overlay);
    m_frame_preview.setParent(this);
}
   ...
```

and xml:

```
<com.myexample.MyFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <View             
        android:id="@+id/top_overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        />
<com.myexample.MyFrameLayout />
```

Then, I have my custom view inherited from FrameLayout

```
public class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout
{   
    private MyActivity m_myActivity;

<constructors...>

    public void setParent(MyActivity _activity)
    {
        m_myActivity = _activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = m_myActivity.m_top_overlay.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = 200;
        m_myActivity.m_top_overlay.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

So, the thing I want is to set height of my view (m_top_view) from java code. Value of 200 is just for example. I will calculate it.
But the way I described doesn't work.

Comment: This is just a guess, but try changing ViewGroup.LayoutParams to FrameLayout.LayoutParams (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: No, it doesnt work either. I think may be I shouldn't use Activity's member and use View object as a child element of MyFrameLayout. But in this case I don't know how to choose the one I need, because I have more than one child element in my real activity.